# Merge two arrays into one array php

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to merge two these two arrays:

```
Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
)

Array
(
    [brown]  => coconut
    [orange]    => orange
)
```

into a single dimensional array like this

```
Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
    [brown]  => coconut
    [orange]    => orange
)
```

Thanks in advance! And I just started programming to please keep that in mind when rating this question.

Comment: Type your question title into Google and see what comes up. That should *always* be the first thing you do (after checking the manual of course).

Comment: Introducing... php documentation !

Comment: This question should be closed because it is a duplicate of the [PHP manual](http://php.net/array_merge).

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [color] => green
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => a
    [3] => b
    [shape] => trapezoid
    [4] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out php documentation for array_merge first?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Basically,

```
$merged_array = array_merge($first_array,$second_array);
```

satisfies your need. The number of arguments can be more than two as well.